# SUMIF function with rules inside the interval

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to set the condition of excel's SUMIF function inside the interval where there are the value to sum?

[image: SUM IF excel]

In the picture above I have to sum only the value in the column BU that are > than "0:15"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for sumif is 
`sumif(range,criteria,[sum range])`
The first argument, *range,* always indicates the values to which the test will be applied.  It sometimes also is the range which will be summed - see argument three,

The second argument, *criteria* is pretty straightforward - you need to build a test.  This could be done entirely in quotes (  "<0:15" ) or could use an expression ( "<" & 1:00 /4 )or could refer to a value in another cell ( "<" & $A$3 ) or some combination.

The third argument, *sum range* is optional.  (That's why it is in brackets)  If it is present, it indicates which values will be summed.  If it is not present, then the values in *range* will be summed.

Try:
`=sumif(bu1:bu100,">00:15")`

The first argument tells what range you are looking at.  The second sets the condition.